# Thinking Sphinx min_inflex_len and delta not working on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

We have an issue with TS min_inflex_len and delta indexes on our production servers

I have everything working in development mode on OSX but when we deploy via capistrano to our Ubuntu server running passenger / apache, both delta indexing seems to stop as well as min_inflex_len

We're deploying as ubuntu user which also runs apache. We had an issue yesterday with production folder not being created but we manually created and I can see a list of the delta files in there now.

I've followed the docs through..

I can see the delta flag set to true on record creation but when searching it doesn't find the record. Once we rebuild index (as ubuntu user) I can find record, but only with full string.

My sphinx.conf file is as follows:

```
production:
    enable_star: 1
    min_infix_len: 3
    bin_path: "/usr/local/bin"
    version: 2.0.5
    mem_limit: 128M
    searchd_log_file: "/var/log/searchd.log"

development:
    min_infix_len: 3
    bin_path: "/usr/local/bin"
    version: 2.0.5
    mem_limit: 128M
```

Rebuild, start and conf work fine and my production.conf file contains this:

```
index company_core
{
  source = company_core_0
  path = /var/www/html/ordering-main/releases/20110831095808/db/sphinx/production/company_core
  charset_type = utf-8
  min_infix_len = 1
  enable_star = 1
}
```

I also have this in my production.rb env file:

```
ThinkingSphinx.deltas_enabled = true 
ThinkingSphinx.updates_enabled = true
```

My searchd.log file only has this in:

```
[Wed Aug 31 09:40:04.437 2011] [ 5485] accepting connections
```

Nothing at all appears in apache error / access log

-- EDIT ---

```
 define_index do
        indexes :name
        has created_at, updated_at
        set_property :delta => true
    end
```

Comment: Hi Jenny - can you add the define_index block for your Company model?

Comment: Sure, have updated my question. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the cause, but the version values in your sphinx.yml are for the version of Sphinx, not Thinking Sphinx - so you may want to run `indexer` to double-check what that value should be (likely one of 0.9.9, 1.10-beta or 2.0.1-beta).

Also: on the server, in `script/console production`, can you share the full output of the following (not interested in the value returned, hence why I'm forcing it to be an empty string - it'll just get in the way otherwise):

```
Company.define_indexes && Company.index_delta; ''
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I've changed version and will rebuild in a moment. However running that command throws an error which is good I suppose. The service looking for company_delta.tmp.spl in the development server's path. How can I change that??

Comment: On further investigation, I can see that /db/sphinx/ in my current folder only contains development. Not sure why it's not creating the folder in production mode..

Comment: How are you running the TS rake tasks?

Comment: Hi pat. As ubuntu user (owns web). Things are looking better although min_inflex isnt working yet. I'd created the folder production on my dev server but it wasn't uploading for some reason. I put a blank file in there are now it sends...

Comment: So deltas are working but infixes aren't? What's the query you're using to test the latter?

Comment: It would seem that way, yes. If I search for tes - the result should show a few test customers. But the logs show "Sphinx  Found 0 results". Searching for test reveals all of them. On dev. server it works fine.

Comment: I've spotted that I can use tes* now on the production server. The two machines are behaving quite differently. I guess that's the versioning? Thanks for help J

Comment: Which versions of Sphinx are you running on dev and production? Mind you, yes, best way to test is using wildcards, I've not found it works reliably without them.

Comment: Im on 2.0.1 on production and 2.0.2 on development. Am still fiddling. Seems that including wildcard option in sphinx.yml stops min_inflex... (or at least on production).

Answer (score 0):

``
delta not working on production server for passenger user, you have to give the write permission to your passenger user when creating index and write it to db/sphinx/production folder.

Or you can set two line in your nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
  passenger_user_switching off;   
  passenger_default_user root;
```

Example:

```
passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.0;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
passenger_user_switching off;
passenger_default_user root;
```

Comment: I recommend *not* using the root as your default user - from a security perspective, it's not a smart move at all.

Comment: Thanks pat, But it was showing nobody and nogroup when writing to  my db/sphinx/production folder. as a result of this no index are updating. How will I resolve this problem.

Comment: Passenger will use the owner of your app files by default - and that user should be invoking the TS rake tasks as well. So maybe fix the ownership of your Rails app files?